# Retrieve data from database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem when I fetching data from database and row it I Got an error.
How To fetch data From database using while and row it.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in

Thanks in advance..

Here is my Code..

```
 <body>
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$iqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemcode,itemname,brandname,quantity FROM table_inventory WHERE id = ?");
$iqry->bind_param('i', $id);
$iqry->execute();
$iqry->bind_result($itemcode,$itemname,$brandname,$quantity);
$res = $iqry->store_result();

while ($row = $res->fetch()){
  $itemcode = $row['itemcode'];
  $itemname = $row['itemname'];
  $brandname = $row['brandname'];
  $quantity = $row['quantity'];
}
?>

    <form method="post" name="increasing" action="save.php">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Itemcode</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="itemcode" required="required"  value="<?php echo $itemcode; ?>">/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Itemname</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="itemname" required="required"  value="<?php echo $itemname; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Brandname</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="brandname" required="required" value="<?php echo $brandname; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Quantity</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" required="required" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Save"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<body>
```

Comment: Have you consulted the mysqli manual?

Comment: Plug your error message into Google and select any result that piques your interest - there are hundreds!

Comment: You should read the manual for [`mysqli_stmt::store_result`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up `mysqli_stmt` and `mysqli_result` methods.

Try making the following changes:

1. `LIMIT` your resultset to one

   ```
   ... FROM table_inventory WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1
   ```
2. Stick with the `mysqli_stmt` as you seem to be further along with that

   ```
   $iqry->bind_param('i', $id);
   $iqry->execute();
   $iqry->bind_result($itemcode, $itemname, $brandname, $quantity);

   if (!$iqry->fetch()) {
       throw new Exception('No results found for ID ' . $id, 404);
   }

   // You can now use $itemcode, $itemname, $brandname and $quantity,
   // they will all be set

   ?>

   <form ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks For help
but I got an error.
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No results found for ID ' in Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
And try to add your suggestion to my codes
`$iqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemcode,itemname,brandname,quantity FROM table_inventory WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$iqry->execute();
$iqry->bind_result($itemcode,$itemname,$brandname,$quantity);
if (!$iqry->fetch()) {
    throw new Exception('No results found for ID ' . $id, 404);
}
while ($row = $iqry->fetch()){
$itemcode = $row['itemcode'];}`
Sorry For the newbie question

Comment: @user3335368 Pretty obvious really. Your `$id` parameter is empty. You probably don't have a `?id=` in your URL. *Actually*, it looks like you've missed the `bind_param` line

Comment: Thanks For reply sir @Phil..
But I don't know how to do this..
I tried to retrieve again but no error and no result found..

Comment: @user3335368 **Do you have the `bind_param` line?** The code in your comment above does not contain that line. You need to add that **and** call your script so the `$_GET['id']` value is populated by providing the `id` parameter in the URL query string. For example `http://localhost/inventory.php?id=123`

Comment: Hi thanks again sir @Phil.
$id = $_GET['id'];

$iqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemcode,itemname,brandname,quantity FROM table_inventory WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$iqry->bind_param('i', $id);
$iqry->execute();
$iqry->bind_result($itemcode,$itemname,$brandname,$quantity);

  if (!$iqry->fetch()) {
    throw new Exception('No results found for ID ' . $id, 404);
}

this is the code ..

and this is i want to 

[retrieve](http://pastebin.com/NDj8WmDG)
Thanks for ur help..